# Group form fields in Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I want to group fields in symfony2. For example wrap them in a div and place headlines in between:

```
<form>
<div class="step-1">
    <h3>Step 1</h3>
    Field 1
    Field 2
</div>
<div class="step-2">
    <h3>Step 2</h3>
    Field 3
    Field 4
</div>
</form>
```

The problem is the form got very much fields so i cant render them one by one in the template. Isnt there any option when adding fields? Like:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->addGroup('step-1')
```

Or how can i handle this?

Comment: A possible solution is to use a list in Twig in order to display fields without duplicating code.

Comment: @n.1 200+ or 2000+ ... it doesnt matter. its just too much to handle manual one by one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Twig can help you to display multiple fields with a minimal code:

```twig
<form>
<div class="step-1">
    <h3>Step 1</h3>
    {% for field in [ 'field1', 'field2']
        if (attribute(form, field) is defined) %}
        {{ form_row(attribute(form, field)) }}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<div class="step-2">
    <h3>Step 2</h3>
    {% for field in [
        'field3',
        'field4',
        'field5',
        'field6'
    ] if (attribute(form, field) is defined) %}
        {{ form_row(attribute(form, field)) }}
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{# Display the other fields #}
{{ form_rest(form) }}

</form>
```

Comment: Thats very close to what i wanted. But still I have to rewrite all 200 fields in controller and in template. Also if i delete a field in controller i have to delete it in the template, too.

Comment: Yes, you have to rewrite the fields in the template, but not in the controller. I can add a test to check that each field exists before attempting to display it. That's the best solution I have. I'm going to update my answer.

Answer (score 16):

I found out, according to [this post](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4294#issuecomment-5841596)(Thanks "n.1" for the link) it is possible to group within controller:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add(
                $this->createFormBuilder()->create('step1', 'form', array('virtual' => true))
                ->add('field1', 'text')
                ->add('field2', 'text')
            )
```

Which gives following template:

```
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <label class="required">Step1</label>
  <div id="form_step1">
    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <label class="required" for="form_step1_field1">Field1</label>
      <input id="form_step1_field1" type="text" required="required" name="form[step1][field1]">
      <input id="form_step1_field2" type="text" required="required" name="form[step1][field1]">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which i can theme the way i want to. But also "bschussek" wrote:

> The structure in your form class shouldn't necessarily be related to the structure in your layout. You can structure the fields in the HTML in whichever way you like.

So maybe the best practice is not to use the controller for structuring and I should prefer the practice from "n.1"

Answer (score 8):

The structure in your form class shouldn't necessarily be related to the structure in your layout. You can structure the fields in yout HTML in whichever way you like. In your case you would put your step headings just like you did in your Q, e.g.:

```
<div class="step-1">
    <h3>Step 1</h3>
    {{ form_widget(form.field1) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.field2) }}
</div>
```

If you still interested to group forms (I did not test that):

```
$builder->add(
    $builder->create('step1', 'form', array('virtual' => true))
        ->add('field1', 'text')
        ->add('field2', 'text')
);
```

[Source](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4294#issuecomment-5841596).

Comment: Note that for Symfony3 you should use `inherit_data` instead of `virtual` property

Comment: if you're using second option (grouping fileds in a form type), symfony3 and you need to add fields with foreach - create group like above only without `add`: `$builder->add($builder->create('step1', 'form', array('inherit_data' => true))` and then inside `foreach` use `$builder->get('step1')->add('something')`